# nginx rewrite rule for redirection

Tags: nginx, playframework-2.3

I have two apps running on host1:7000 and host2:7000. I am fronting the two hosts by an nginx reverse proxy, where I want mydomain.com/admin to point to host1:7000/portal and mydomain.com/user to host2:7000/portal.

I have written the following config

```
listen       80;
server_name  mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;

location ~ ^/admin/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass $scheme://<IP-ADDRESS>/$1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}
```

I can get to mydomain.com/admin to be redirected to host1:7000/portal but when the app redirects from host1:7000/portal on to host1:7000/login via relative path, in the browser I see mydomain.com/login. What do I need to do to get the second redirect go mydomain/admin/login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do people use regexps for no reason and have all kind of problems with it?…

```
location /admin/ {
    proxy_pass http://host1:7000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}
```

This will automatically strip `/admin/` from proxied request and prepend it in `Location` header (which is used in redirect).

See [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) and [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) docs.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I also figured that I can't do this just through redirect as JS code would reference static assets for the two portal at web root. I need the apps to add a prefix to the URI as well.